# Size of picture in background repeat?

Tags: html, css

Hope all you are doing good.

I have an area on the webpage where I want to add the background picture.

I have two Images.

One I have a background picture of icon [which small tittle block image size almost about 5kb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDCiU.png)

And I have a Background image which fits the whole background-size is almost about 100kb. which fit to the screen.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Qna.jpg)

I want to improve the page speed so if I add a little icon image which repeats my self and look good in the background.

Can you please tell when the image repeat in the background does its size also increase like if the size is now 5kb when image repeat one more time its size now 10kb?

Can you please suggest me which one I have to use one big image or small icons repeat.

Hope you got my point.

Comment: small image repeat.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha thanks for your reply can you please explain this so i get the whole concept

Comment: yes use small image and repeat it using CSS.image only load the first time and repeat it which will save some data.this is a very common technique

Answer (score 2):

Use small icon, preferably a GIF image. Once that is done, you don't have to necessarily specify the size.

The code below repeat a background image both vertically and horizontally

```
 body {   background-image: url("my_image.gif");   
          background-repeat: repeat; 
      }
```

If you want to repeat it horizontally, use the code below

```
body {
  background-image: url("my_image.gif");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a full description on how this works go to this link but for the solution you need the code is below as well

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

if you want to repeat it horizontally you can use:

background-repeat:repeat-x;

if vertically use:

background-repeat:repeat-y;

if you want it to not repeat use:

background-repeat:no-repeat;

hope this solution helps